# Access denied - mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

I have got the following message in my browser:

```
An error occurred in script'/home/greentes/public_html/includes/mysql.inc.php' on line 10: 
mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (42000/1044): 
    Access denied for user 'greentes_uson'@'localhost' to database 'greentes_pdfshop'
```

Line 10, of mysql.inc.php:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

What could be causing this error please? Is this sufficient information to answer this question? Thank you

Comment: You got your access details wrong, and/or you're connecting from the wrong host. Pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: [Reasons for MySQL authentication error: "Access denied for user 'xxx'@'yyy'"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246296/reasons-for-mysql-authentication-error-access-denied-for-user-xxxyyy)

Comment: Is the user mentioned given access to the database? Sounds like the user isn't allowed to access

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit there is no need to be rude. It isn't self explanatory if your still learning php/mysql, & are an absolute novice!

Comment: @Matthew: I haven't been rude. If you have "access denied", then there is something wrong with your access credentials. There is nothing unique to PHP or MySQL about that. And/or a quick Google search would tell you this.

Comment: WOW, I have just been banned for asking questions on this site, as apparently this question didn't meet guidelines. As an absolute newbie I didn't know the answer. Strange site. cc @lightness races in orbit. Obviously, newbies aren't suppose to use this site - only for 'experts'. All newbies ask questions that appear 'self explanatory' to prof.

Comment: I have only posted 2 other questions on this site, both were + rated. Then I ask one question which is apparently 'self explanatory' & get banned from asking questions. @Lightness  Races in Orbit.

Comment: I don't know why you keep notifying me in your comments. How are you "banned from asking questions"? I suggest you go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com if you want to discuss site mechanics, as this is not the place.

Answer (score 2):

The user `greentes_uson` does not have MySQL permissions to access database `greentes_pdfshop`. This is most likely caused by an incorrectly entered password, but you should also check that:

- The user exists
- The user has been granted permissions on that database
- You're using the right user / database name

Comment: Thank-you, it was a permissions problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to the database.

I think your mysqluser has no permissions to access greentes_pdfshop

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the constants:

DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, and DB_NAME

contain the intended values. Usually, if the username is not specify, it defaults to user the script belongs to, if I remember correctly. Also, make sure your mysql server is running See:

http://theos.in/desktop-linux/tip-that-matters/how-do-i-restart-mysql-server/

For the constants I mentioned above, look for the pattern:

DEFINE('DB_HOST', $somevalue);

If your codes. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank-you, for helping me progress with my learning. It was a permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it might be an insufficent amount of information, it probably is.

we need to see some more of your code, as frederick mentions - the problem could also be in your database config!

how did you configure the database?

did you restrict the users from connecting from certain hosts?